# Having some trouble makeing this Turtle Race game in tkinter module

Tags: python, tkinter, python-turtle

Essentially what I said in the title. I am having some trouble detecting a win with tkinker and would appreciate some guidance.I think my original race may have been a little poorly done as well.

````
from tkinter.simpledialog import askstring
import random
import time
root = tk.Tk()
import turtle
wn = turtle.Screen()
wn.bgcolor('lightblue')

color1 = askstring('Enter Color', 'Please enter the turtle color')
t1 = turtle.Turtle()
t2 = turtle.Turtle()
t1.color(color1)
color2 = askstring('Enter Color', 'Please enter the turtle color')
t2.color(color2)
t1.shape('turtle')
t2.shape('turtle')
t1.left(90)
t2.left(90)
t1.goto(-100, -100)
t2.goto(100,  -100)

finish_1 = turtle.Turtle()
finish_1.penup()
finish_1.goto(-100, 100)
finish_1.pendown()
finish_1.circle(20)
finish_1.hideturtle()

finish_2 = turtle.Turtle()
finish_2.penup()
finish_2.goto(100, 100)
finish_2.pendown()
finish_2.circle(20)
finish_2.hideturtle()

for x in range(100):
  t1.fd(random.randrange(10))
  t2.fd(random.randrange(10))
if t1.xcor: 100
turtle.write((color1), move=False, align="left", font=("Arial", 72, "normal"))  
if t2.xcor: 100
turtle.write((color2), move=False, align="left", font=("Arial", 72, "normal"))
time.sleep(3)```
````

Answer (score 0):

First, python cant recognize your window because you've imported just a function from tkinter and not the entire library :

```
from tkinter.simpledialog import askstring
```

What it does is that you import the function you need (here *askstring*). You actually need to import the whole library : `import tkinter as tk`.
You import tkinter and name it *tk*. (You have use `root = tk.Tk()`).

Then you need to use the *askstring* function. You'll have to specifie the whole path to the function instead : `tk.simpledialog.askstring`.

Here is a link to the official documentation on how to import a library :
https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html

And here is your whole source code modified :

```py
import tkinter as tk
import random
import time
root = tk.Tk()

import turtle
wn = turtle.Screen()
wn.bgcolor('lightblue')

color1 = tk.simpledialog.askstring('Enter Color', 'Please enter the turtle color')
t1 = turtle.Turtle()
t2 = turtle.Turtle()
t1.color(color1)
color2 = tk.simpledialog.askstring('Enter Color', 'Please enter the turtle color')
t2.color(color2)
t1.shape('turtle')
t2.shape('turtle')
t1.left(90)
t2.left(90)
t1.goto(-100, -100)
t2.goto(100,  -100)

finish_1 = turtle.Turtle()
finish_1.penup()
finish_1.goto(-100, 100)
finish_1.pendown()
finish_1.circle(20)
finish_1.hideturtle()

finish_2 = turtle.Turtle()
finish_2.penup()
finish_2.goto(100, 100)
finish_2.pendown()
finish_2.circle(20)
finish_2.hideturtle()

for x in range(100):
  t1.fd(random.randrange(10))
  t2.fd(random.randrange(10))
if t1.xcor: 100
turtle.write((color1), move=False, align="left", font=("Arial", 72, "normal"))  
if t2.xcor: 100
turtle.write((color2), move=False, align="left", font=("Arial", 72, "normal"))
time.sleep(3)
```

I don't really understand why you want to create a window but anyway.

Have a nice day

Answer (score 0):

Turtle is designed to be used either *standalone* or *embedded* in a tkinter program.  You've used the standalone API in a tkinter embedded situation.  This appears to be the case just to access the tkinter `askstring()` method.

We can turn this into a standalone turtle program by substituting the `textinput()` method.  Here's a rework of your code that does that along with fixing bugs in the winner test:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle
from random import randrange

FONT = ('Arial', 72, 'normal')

screen = Screen()
screen.bgcolor('lightblue')

color1 = screen.textinput("Enter Color", "Please enter the turtle color")
t1 = Turtle()
t1.shape('turtle')
t1.color(color1)
t1.setheading(90)
t1.penup()
t1.goto(-100, -100)

color2 = screen.textinput("Enter Color", "Please enter the turtle color")
t2 = Turtle()
t2.shape('turtle')
t2.color(color2)
t2.setheading(90)
t2.penup()
t2.goto(100, -100)

finish_1 = Turtle()
finish_1.hideturtle()
finish_1.penup()
finish_1.goto(-100, 100)
finish_1.pendown()
finish_1.circle(20)

finish_2 = Turtle()
finish_2.hideturtle()
finish_2.penup()
finish_2.goto(100, 100)
finish_2.pendown()
finish_2.circle(20)

marker = Turtle()
marker.hideturtle()

for _ in range(100):
    t1.forward(randrange(10))

    if t1.ycor() >= 100:
        marker.write(color1, align='center', font=FONT)
        break

    t2.forward(randrange(10))

    if t2.ycor() >= 100:
        marker.write(color2, align='center', font=FONT)
        break

screen.exitonclick()
```